# AFNetworking - Timeout Interval not as expected after 60 Sec Waiting

Tags: ios, swift, afnetworking

AFNetworking 3.1.0 is working as expected when we set timeout window as 60 or below but when i am setting 120 or larger value its actually not waiting for 120 sec.

Note: Server is not getting timeout.

Below i have mention few data sets of my analysis.

Expected - Actual

80 Sec - 68 Sec

20 Sec - 20 Sec

100 Sec - 66 Sec

120 Sec - 60 Sec

Does anyone face this problem or its expected but not documented.

Code Snippet:

```
let manager = AFHTTPSessionManager(baseURL: URL(string: serverAddress))
                manager.responseSerializer = AFJSONResponseSerializer()
                manager.requestSerializer = AFJSONRequestSerializer()
                manager.requestSerializer.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

manager.requestSerializer.timeoutInterval = 120
```

Comment: how are you setting timeout interval?

Comment: Maybe because of your server timeout. Timeout for server and your request are different.

Comment: Kamran https://stackoverflow.com/users/4061501/lal-krishna - I have edited my question. pls check.

Comment: Lal Krishna https://stackoverflow.com/users/4061501/lal-krishna- No, this not the case. I have explicitly put the delay on server for this testing.

Answer (score 0):

Initially i thought something wrong with AFNetworing time out window beyond 60, But actually server was getting timed out. This i came to know after testing in postman.

It is giving gateway timeout - 504